# Why snackbar is going out of the screen?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

Basically I'm trying to show `snackbar` at the top .But the problem is it's upper half part is going out of the screen . Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Code:

```
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(search_btn, content, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        sbView.setClickable(true);
        sbView.setFocusable(true);
        sbView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        TextView tv = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#001919"));
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) sbView.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        sbView.setLayoutParams(params);
        snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything is alright, maybe you could try adding a topMargin to the layout params.